# Accessing on playing in dynamically created audio object

Tags: jquery, dom, audio, html5-audio

I have a simple plays counter for audio files on a webpage. It works for the audio file initially loaded, but not when another jQuery ajax has updated it to a different file with same class etc (the file plays)

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            /*now events will only be bound to this instance*/ 
            $('body .sermonmp3').on('playing',function(){
                /* within event callbacks keep searches within the main container element*/                     
                var fileID=$(this).attr('id');
                console.log(fileID);
                var data = {file_id: fileID ,security:ChurchAdminAjax.security};

                jQuery.post(ChurchAdminAjax.ajaxurl, { 'action': 'ca_mp3_action','data':   data }, 
                    function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        $('body .plays').html(response);

                    }
                );

            });
```

});

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by putting the code in a function and calling it each time a new audio element is created.

```
        function bindEvents(){

            $('body .sermonmp3').on('playing',function(){

                var fileID=$(this).attr('id');
                console.log(fileID);
                var data = {file_id: fileID ,security:ChurchAdminAjax.security};

                jQuery.post(ChurchAdminAjax.ajaxurl, { 'action': 'ca_mp3_action','data':   data }, 
                    function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        $('body .plays').html(response);

                    }
                );

            });
        }
```